# How to fix the syntax of a function which is in string format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file containing python functions in string format. My code reads each function from the text file, feeds it with the appropriate inputs and then runs it. To run a function string (for example `fun_str`) from the text file, I use the following snippet in my code:

```
dict = {}
exec(fun_str, globals(), dict)
f, = dict.values()
f()
```

As long as each function string has the python standard syntax (in terms of indentations, new lines, etc), the code works well. However, if the code reads a function string such as:

```
"def fun(list): output_list = [] for i in list: if i not in output_list: output_list.append(i) return output_list"
```

(all in one line)

then `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` is raised with `^^^` under `for`.

Is there any built-in module or any approach to fix the function string so that it follows the standard syntax  before it is run by `exec`?

Comment: Did you write the functions? If you did then you can add a semi colon before `for` and also before `return`.

Comment: @EDD no the text file is not written by me.

Comment: If there was some easy, automatic way to fix broken syntax, Python wouldn't require correct syntax in the first place. (Heck, it wouldn't really *have* syntax at that point.)

Comment: Why are you doing it this way instead of just making the file with the functions a regular python file and importing it?

Comment: @JaredSmith Even if I change the file extension from `.txt` to `.py` and import it, the syntax error will be raised.

Comment: Yeah, you may have to edit the file. But you're probably going to have to do that anyway, so.... why not just make it a Python file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take some python code and remove all newlines, it is not necessaraily possible to convert back to the original.

For example:

```py
def f(x): if x == None: return doSomething(x)
```

could mean either:

```py
def f(x):
    if x == None:
        return doSomething(x)
```

or

```py
def f(x):
    if x == None:
        return
    doSomething(x)
```

So it wouldn't be possible unless you know something about that code that allows you to unambiguously convert it back to its original meaning.